# Create Dataframe with rows made for each string appearing in a column of another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If you have a dataframe as follows:

```
genre                 mean_average_budget
horror thriller       x
romance comedy        y 
action thriller       z
documentary           a
comedy documentary    b
```

How could one be made in which the rows are the individual appearances of each string in the genre column?
Eg:

```
genre                 mean_average_budget
horror                h
thriller              i 
action                k
documentary           l
comedy                m
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
new_df = df.set_index('mean_average_budget').genre.str.split().\
    apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(1,drop = True).\
    reset_index(name = 'genre')

    mean_average_budget genre
0   x                   horror
1   x                   thriller
2   y                   romance
3   y                   comedy
4   z                   action
5   z                   thriller
6   a                   documentary
7   b                   comedy
8   b                   documentary
```

To find mean, try this for numeric data

```
new_df.groupby('genre')['mean_average_budget'].mean()
```

If you want to aggregate the strings

```
new_df.groupby('genre')['mean_average_budget'].apply('+'.join)
```

Comment: Keyerror means your column name is not  'mean_average_budget' . Print df.columns to check the exact column name and substitute that with  'mean_average_budget'  and it would work

Comment: That worked perfectly for producing separate rows with repetitions. But could it be done with the repeated rows aggregated and the new mean calculated? For example with one documentary row with mean (a+b)/2, one comedy row with (y+b)/2 etc.